# How to get the horizontal VictoryAxis line to be drawn at a position other than zero?

Tags: victory-charts

I have a graph with some bars representing sales and a line representing the goal that each type of sale should reach:

I would like for the horizontal axis line to be at position y=-20 instead of position y=0, without having to add 20 to the y and y0 inside the date array and the tickValues of the VictoryAxis with the goal line.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-bar-forked-gxqqjp?file=/src/App.js)